# Adding failing optional initializer in Swift in extension

Tags: swift, initialization, swift3

I'm trying to add a convenience failing initializer to `UIFont` as an extension. So `UIFont` already has a failing initializer:

```
open class UIFont : NSObject, NSCopying {
    ...

    public init?(name fontName: String, size fontSize: CGFloat)
    ...
}
```

So I want to create a convenience initializer that would call this one, something similar to the code below:

```
public convenience init?(name fontName: String, size fontSize: CGFloat, weight fontWeight: String) {
    self.init(name: fontName + "-" + fontWeight, size: fontSize)
}
```

So far so good, this works perfectly. Now I want to add some custom logic, for example:

```
public convenience init?(name fontName: String, size fontSize: CGFloat, weight fontWeight: String) {
    if let font = self.init(name: fontName + "-" + fontWeight, size: fontSize) {
        self = font
    }
    else if let font = self.init(name: fontName, size: fontSize) {
        self = font
    }
    else {
        //
        // Add some failback code
        //
        return nil
    }
}
```

This is where problems start. What I want to do is a basic convenience API, but I cannot manage to get the font conditionally initialized. In the upper example there is a syntax error in `if let font = self.init` line, and it says: `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '()'`. But this initializer actually is optional, as defined by `UIFont` class (see above), so I don't see the problem. I tried returning font instead of assigning it to `self`, but does not make a difference.

So my question is: **How to correctly implement conditional logic in a failing initializer?**

*It could be that I am doing something wrong here, or this could just be Swift missing feature/bug?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift initialisation is one of the most confusing part of the language, especially if you're coming from Objective-C. The short answer is that:

> Unlike Objective-C initializers, Swift initializers do not return a value.

(from https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html).

Therefore when you write:

```
public convenience init?(
    name fontName: String, size fontSize: CGFloat, weight fontWeight: String
) {
    let font = self.init(name: fontName + "-" + fontWeight, size: fontSize)
```

the type of `font` is `Void`. Yeah, I know, it does raise an eyebrow, since it's different model than in ObjC. In Swift you delegate the work of initialisation to another initialiser, but you're not managing the instance directly. So you can call it a missing feature.

The easy workaround is to make a factory method instead of initialiser:

```
public static func from(
    name fontName: String, size fontSize: CGFloat, weight fontWeight: String
) -> UIFont? {
    if let font = self.init(name: fontName + "-" + fontWeight, size: fontSize) {
        return font
    }
    else if let font = self.init(name: fontName, size: fontSize) {
        return font
    }
    else {
        //
        // Add some failback code
        //
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of the factory method as a workaround (that is how I currently handle it), but I was looking for a better API over the initialization. But according to this blog post, https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17 I was hoping there is something.

Comment: I see what you mean. The difference is that the blogpost shows initialisation of value types, which follow copy semantics. For value types `self` can be mutated. It applies both to initializer and any other method marked as `mutating`. While I have no great mental model for it, please refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_339 for more details on differences between reference type and value type initialization delegation.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, I'll accept this answer as "missing feature". Thanks!